# Execute function on php

Tags: php, html, forms, submit-button

I recently start the php programming. However, I encountered a problem about running a function on php file. My php file is listed as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="aaaaa" />

    <title>Untitled 3</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="Test()" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>

<?php
echo "Hello";
function Test()
{
    echo "Goodbye";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

After running the program, a webpage is observed with A button entitled submit and the word "Hello". However, After click on the button, the webpage "This page cannot be displayed" is observed. But I respect the word "Goodbye" is shown. I transferred the php code to another file, but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: another 132 points on the php tag @chris85 and you'll be able to close those off in one go ;-) bet you can't wait! *lol*

Comment: after seeing a comment you left in one of the answers being *"However, the webpage "This page can't be displayed" is again observed."*, I'm thinking you're trying to run this as `file:///` rather than a host.

Comment: I am writing the code and runing it the phpDesigner 8. I set the localhost in a folder in my computer.

Answer (score 1):

actions in forms aren't functions like JavaScript.  You are trying to run Test() on submit which isn't a thing.  What you want is action to be action=" "

In reality you should be doing something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="aaaaa" />

    <title>Untitled 3</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    echo "Hello";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Goodbye";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

If you WANT to use a function....

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
    <meta name="author" content="aaaaa" />

    <title>Untitled 3</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php
    echo "Hello";

function test(){
   echo "Goodbye";
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    test();
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Lets say he file name is test.php where you have put all your code so the action values should be test.php

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" >
```

Comment: You're theoretically correct, but what about the function they wish to use; what happens to that?

Comment: I'll edit it, but there's no need for a function in this instance..

Comment: *"no need for a function in this instance"* - Yeah but what if they "want" to use a function, along with a probable JS method with ajax etc.? We don't really know what's going on in other people's heads ;-)

Comment: They can still declare their `function test()`, but they would only call it it their page had been submitted:

`<form method="post">`
...

`<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { test() } ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  it's been edited for an if they WANT case.

Comment: @clearshot66 that makes a lot more sense :-) *cheers*

Comment: I think you may want to reload this entire question with the new comments ;-) the plot thickens as it were.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I copy and past the code and run the code. However, when I click the button, nothing is done.

Comment: Are you running this on a server or locally @MohammadTahayeAbadi

Comment: I am locally running it.l

Comment: @MohammadTahayeAbadi PHP doesn't function locally it's a server side language. It has to be run on a PHP enabled server. If you want to test and run PHP code locally I'd suggest using something like this : https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html

Comment: I installed XAMPP to make my computer as a php virtual server. I have also started Appache and MySQL on the control panel of XAMPP.